# Need clarification on macOS proxy configuration settings

Tags: mac, proxy, macos

I'm attempting to configure the proxy settings for a MacBook to work in my office. My company uses a proxy pac file and provided me the URL, what I am unclear about is the other options. I confirmed we dont have WPAD setup, so I assume that there is no reason to enable Auto Proxy Discovery. Additionally, when I check the proxy.pac file, I can see that there are a number of domains and ip address ranges that are configured to bypass the proxy, so my assumption is that I dont need to modify the "Bypass proxy settings for these Hosts & Domains" section, would that be used if my company didnt have a pac file and I was entering the proxy server address for Web Proxy and Secure Web Proxy?

Appreciate any insight that can be provided, I'm really looking to understand the various settings and options and which should be used in conjunction because Mac support is non-existent so I will be supporting myself.

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

if you a .pac file. u can use it with the following syntax https://ip_addr:port/proxy.pac [or could] in Firfox. The section just below the manual proxy settings.
hope helps